# Compare id's stored in XML to id's stored in a table

Tags: xml, postgresql, extract

I have XML stored in a table called tbl_products, I want to extract the ID from this XML `<id>` and return the ID if the ID does appear in a different table.

I'm aware this may be worded badly, but I'm finding it difficult to explain.

```
SELECT *, cast(xpath('/objects/id/text()', objectsXML) as text[])
FROM "productData".tbl_products
WHERE personId = 314
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM prids)
LIMIT 15
```

Example XML

```
 <objects>
     <id>
         521GT67
     </id>
 </objects>
```

Does '521GT67' appear anywhere in the table tbl_products?

So I'm looking to check if the ids appear anywhere at all in the second table.

The second table contains a product per column, and the ids going downwards in rows.

This statement returns nothing, but I am sure it should return at least 10 rows.
It acts the same regardless of

```
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM prids)
```

My desired output would just be a list of id's that appear in the second table (in any column)

Based on @G_H 's comment, which seems very logical. 
I now have the following

```
SELECT *, cast(xpath('/objects/id/text()', objectsXML) as text[])
FROM "productData".tbl_products p
WHERE personId = 314
AND EXISTS (SELECT ids FROM prids r WHERE p.cast(xpath('/objects/id/text()',    objectsXML) = r.ids)
LIMIT 15
```

Which returns the error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 5: LIMIT 15
```

Seems much more promising

Comment: Show sample data and desired output.

Comment: Ok, help is appreciated.

Comment: `personId = 314` does not exist

Comment: By selecting the two tables individually, I return data. So unfortunately that isnt the cause

Comment: Is it intentional that you have `(SELECT * FROM prids)` in the first statement? Shouldn't it select only IDs, or have a WHERE clause with the ID from the XML in that subquery? Anyway, check if the ID taken from the XML doesn't have whitespace around it. You may need to trim it if the XPath expression literally returns the entire <id> element content.